# Cannot convert 'const T' to 'template<T>function'

Tags: c++

I can't understand why I'm getting a conversion error on my Node ctor, the node constructor accepts 'const T&' as the first parameter and thats what my insert method is passing into the constructor but for some reason its still throwing me that error.

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const Record' to 'SortedList<>::Node *

***SortedList is of type 'Record' but if I type anything inbetween <> everything in between the brackets will disappear.***

List class:

```
class SortedList{
struct Node{
    T data_;
    Node* next_;
    Node* prev_;
    Node(const T& data=T{},Node* nx=nullptr,Node* pr=nullptr){
        data_ = data;
        next_ = nx;
        prev_ = pr;
    }
};
Node* front_;
Node* back_;
public:
class const_iterator{ 
    friend class SortedList;
  protected:
    Node* curr_;
    const_iterator(Node* n){ 
        curr_ = n; 
    }
  public:
    const_iterator(){
        curr_ = nullptr;
    }
    const_iterator operator++(){
        curr_ = curr_->next_;

        return *this;
    }
    const_iterator operator++(int){ //advances curr returns old
        const_iterator old = *this;
        curr_ = curr_->next_;

        return old;
    }
    const_iterator operator--(){
        curr_ = curr_->prev_;

        return *this;
    }
    const_iterator operator--(int){
        const_iterator temp = *this;
        curr_ = curr_->prev_;

        return temp;
    }
    bool operator==(const_iterator rhs){
        return curr_->data_ == rhs.curr_->data_;
    }
    bool operator!=(const_iterator rhs){
        return curr_->data_ != rhs.curr_->data_;
    }
    bool operator<(const_iterator rhs){
        return curr_->data_ < rhs.curr_->data_;
    }
    const T& operator*()const{
        return curr_->data_;
    }
};
```

Where the conversion error is being throw:

```
template <typename T>
typename SortedList<T>::iterator SortedList<T>::insert(const T& data){
   Node* n(data);
   iterator it_temp(n);
   iterator sort(front_);
   while (sort < it_temp){
       ++sort;
}
   n.next_ = sort.curr_; 
   n.prev_ = sort.curr_->prev_;
   sort.curr_->prev_->next_ = n;
   sort.curr_->prev_ = n;
}
```

The error is specifically being throw where Node* n is being constructed in the insert function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot construct a pointer like this

```
Node* n(data);
```

You'd have to, for example, use `new`

```
Node* n = new Node(data);
```

Comment: thank-you so much I've been stuck on this error for atleast 2 hours.